# Why is the terminal output of environment variables, like "echo %PRIVATE_KEY%" blank

Tags: visual-studio-code

I was trying to echo value of a variable in my env variable in Windows. I successfully echoed it using this command in cmd `echo %PRIVATE_KEY%` but couldn't output the value in my vscode terminal ...using the same command

Comment: What kind of terminal did you have open in VSCode. A bash prompt? powershell? A command prompt?

Comment: It seems like your title is cut in the middle...

Answer (score 1):

According to [the documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference#_environment-variables), this line should do the trick :

```
echo ${env:PRIVATE_KEY}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  "key": "alt+e",               // whatever keybinding you want
  "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
  "args": {
    "text": "echo ${env:PRIVATE_KEY}"
    // "text": "${env:PATH}"
  },
}
```

Those values won't resolve unless you go through the `sendSequence` command to send them to the terminal.